# Intermittent 502 when using cloudflare on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I am hosting my website on azure and using cloudflare for dns and proxy.

Recently I started experiencing a problem where if I refresh a page a number of times, eventually I get the cloudflare 502 page. Refreshing the page again and it loads fine.

If I refresh the page without using cloudflare, i.e. I go straight to {mydomain}.azurewebsites.net I don't get the issue.

So obviously the problem is server/cloudflare side config. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I think it is related to this issue: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/random-502-errors-for-last-3-days-caused-by-illegal-request-header-injected-by-cf-reverse-proxy/202061

Answer (score 0):

The 502 Bad Gateway error is an HTTP status code that means that one server on the internet received an invalid response from another server... so as it stands you don't have enough information to figure out what is going on here.

You will need to find a way to get the web server logs from your server on Azure and possibly also the logs from Cloudflare.